# Is it possible to implement an interface into another interface with GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I want to make a deeper abstraction.

```
interface Person {
  name
}

interface SpecialPerson implements Person{
  name
  speciality
}

type PrettyAwesomPerson implements SpecialPerson{
  name
  speciality
  awesomeThings
}
```

Is something like this possible? The way I mentioned it is not working and I sadly cannot find a good documentation or another question to this

Comment: Alright, it may be a JVM language but if it is not compiled using javac I dont know if we can use the java tag here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GraphQL spec [now supports interfaces implementing other interfaces](http://spec.graphql.org/draft/#sec-Interfaces.Interfaces-Implementing-Interfaces):

> When defining an interface that implements another interface, the implementing interface must define each field that is specified by the implemented interface... Transitively implemented interfaces (interfaces implemented by the interface that is being implemented) must also be defined on an implementing type or interface.

This is available in the (JavaScript) reference implementation as of version 15.0.0. I don't believe the Java implementation supports it yet but should in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The spec currently does not allow this, [but will](http://spec.graphql.org/draft/#sec-Interfaces.Interfaces-Implementing-Interfaces) in the near future. [The RFC that introduces this feature](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/pull/373) has been merged, and the support is already present in the reference (JS) implementation.

Comment: The spec [now supports it](http://spec.graphql.org/draft/#sec-Interfaces.Interfaces-Implementing-Interfaces)!

Comment: @DanielRearden That's an unreleased draft. But thanks for the update. Added the link to the answer.

Comment: The draft is unreleased, but the functionality was recently added to the reference implementation.